# How to make a single string into a multitude of strings?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string called `e3` which holds the string `1,2,4,5,3,6`. I want to add up all of those numbers up to make the number `21` I was considering doing a for loop for this however I do not know how to turn part of a string into its own value. 
I anyone has any better idea of what to do please comment, or answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for the string and use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for summing.

```js
var e3 = '1,2,4,5,3,6',
    sum = e3.split(',').reduce(function (a, b) { 
      return a + +b; // +b forces b to number
    }, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you used the split() function? I always thought that split() would make the specified value turn into commas, the string will always be with commas.

Comment: its just the other way round. split returns an array with the parts without the string of the splitting string. so `'1,2,3'.split(',')` returns an array with the strings `['1', '2', '3']`.

Comment: Nina is correct. See my answer for details. In short, split separates a string based on ANY separator. For example, it cannot separate the string on "," like in your example. Or an empty space, like so " ", or based on a dash,or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that it is always a comma separated list of numbers, you could split it on the comma into an array and then use array.reduce() to sum them

```
var asString = '1,2,4,5,3,6';
var asArray = asString.split(',');

var total = asArray.reduce(function(prev, current){
    return prev + parseInt(current, 10);
}, 0);

console.log(total) // outputs 21;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var e3 = "1,2,4,5,3,6";
// Split by separator ','
var stringsArr = e3.split(',');

var sum = 0;
// Loop through array of string numbers
stringsArr.forEach(function(str) {
    // get Int from a string
    var strVal = parseInt(str, 10);
  sum += strVal;
});
```

here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Patat/3der647y/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code to do what you need: https://plnkr.co/edit/8LSkZi0oC8msbHI0qOrz?p=preview

At first you use the split method - this separates a string into an array of strings, based on some separator value. In our case, the separator is a comma, but it could be a blank space or something else:

```
var testString = '1,2,4,5,3,6';
var separator = ',';

function splitStringOnCommasAndGetArray(string, separator){
  var arrayOfStrings = string.split(separator);
  return arrayOfStrings;
}
```

After that, we loop through the array and turn each value into a number. We add the numbers, like so:

```
function addUpArray(arrayOfStrings){

  var totalNumber = 0; 

  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
    var currentNum = parseInt(arrayOfStrings[i]);
    console.log(currentNum);
    totalNumber += currentNum;
  }

  return totalNumber; 
}
```